# Python replace argument variable string in while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I want to replace my PA_uat environment naming to uat
eg: PA_uat1 to uat1 , PA_uat6 to uat6
Here is my test.py. I am running it like python test.py RAD4.09 PA_uat2 database

```
import json
from datetime import datetime
from contextlib import redirect_stdout

version = str(sys.argv[1])

env = str(sys.argv[2])
script = str(sys.argv[3])
now = datetime.now()
# dt_string = now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
sdate = now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
print (sdate)

print("%s %s %s" % (version, env, script))
if env == "PA_uat1":
    env = env.replace("PA_uat1", "uat1")
elif env == "PA_uat2":
    env = env.replace("PA_uat2", "uat2")
.
.
elif env == "PA_uat10":
    env = env.replace("PA_uat10", "uat10")
```

This code works and my env gets replaced and can use this env further in code. But I find this a very long code. I tried this using while loop and it don't replace env, and if I print, its never ending loop

```
i = 1
while i < 11:
    env = env.replace("PA_uat[i]", "uat[i]")
    print(env)
```

Is there any way I can replace my env from PA_uat1 to uat1 without using if loop?

Comment: Did you mean: `env = env.replace(f"PA_uat{i}", f"uat{i}")`?

Comment: Also, you need to increment `i`. Or better use `for i in range(11)` loop.

Answer (score 1):

why can't you just use `replace()`! Does not matter whether it's PA_uat1 or PA_uat99!!

```
>>> env="PA_uat1"
>>> env.replace("PA_", "")
'uat1'
>>>
```